# RegEx for removing lines that have the same id in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to remove lines with the same id in `Notepad++`.I have a `.txt` file that has the following structure with the same id

```
1       33.854088   21.766714   abcdeffgffghjkkgfdfghjjh
1       33.854088   21.766714   ghfhsjiwassjss
2       32.856728   23.758888   asdfgdgff
3       37.85834    23.7711     asdfgghgghhg
3       37.85834    23.7711     babanxucndk
```

I want to keep only the first line of each id in the start like that

```
1       33.854088   21.766714   abcdeffgffghjkkgfdfghjjh
2       32.856728   23.758888   asdfgdgff
3       37.85834    23.7711     asdfgghgghhg
```

I have tried to use this regex `^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)` but it only gives me completely identical lines and i just need the first line of every id.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

Match:

```
^((\d+).*)(\r?\n\2.*)+
```

And replace with:

```
\1
```

We match the row ID in group 2, and capture the first line in group 1. Then we continue matching subsequent lines that start with the same ID (lines that start with our back-reference `\2`). We then replace with group 1, which is the first line. Note that this assumes your ID column is ascending.

Live example: https://regex101.com/r/9KCuMn/1

Comment: A better version would be this [`^(\d++).*\K(?:\R+\1\b.*)+`](https://regex101.com/r/9KCuMn/2). No need to define a back-reference as replacement string.